# ¿Se puede usar la función mail() de PHP para enviar unos 3000 correos en un while?

Tags: php, mail

Quisiera saber si es una buena practica utilizar la función `mail()` para el envío masivo de correos y si no me dará fallas por ser usada tantas veces en un mismo ciclo. Realmente quisiera evitar usar PHPMailer, ya que desde el entorno en el que sera usado el sistema no tendrá problemas de SPAM.

Comment: El factor mas importante es que existen algunos servicios de hosting que no permiten el envío de emails masivos, ese es un detalle a considerar y verificar

Comment: Es algo que también esta previsto, solo quisiera saber si la función soporta ese uso, el servidor tiene todo configurado para eso.

Comment: La forma mas facil de saberlo es haciendo la prueba.

Answer (score 1):

Utilizar mail() de php implica que tienes que utilizar algun servicio imap o pop, no es recomendable ya que normalmente los servicios tienen un limite de envio por dia o segun el proveedor que utilices puedes tener un limite de envio entre cada correo enviado. Lo recomendable es utilizar servicios que son exclusivos para envio de correo masivo o campañas publicitarias, casi todos tienen api que puedes utilizar con PHP.

Algunos que puedo mencionar:

1. Sengrid
2. Amazon SES
3. Mailchimp

Answer (score 0):

Los posibles problemas que puedes encontrar al usar mail() para envios masivos de esta forma a simple vista son dos:

1. El tiempo de ejecución del script puede superar el límite establecido en el php.ini
2. El servidor de correo de tu servidor debe permitirte tal cantidad de emails a procesar. Cuando usas mail() no estas enviando nada directamente a los servidores de correo de destino, sino a traves del sistema donde estás ejecutando ese script, el cual tiene su propio MTA para ello. Dicho de otra forma, todos los correos enviados con mail() van a la cola de salida del MTA de tu servidor, por lo tanto este MTA tiene que estar configurado para permitírtelo.  En los hostings compartidos o en determinados paneles de hosting, por defecto limitan ese número de correos para intentar limitar de algun modo su uso por cuentas hackeadas por spammers de forma indiscriminada.